# How to dinamically disable some of the form fields?

Tags: symfony

I need to disable some of the form fields if I edit and object with that form and more than a month has passed since that object was created. I have a porperty `addedAt` for that object. Do I need to use Form event listeners to do so or is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: You could either use events, or simply define another form which handles "old" entities. Inside the controller you then decide which form to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it dynamically, your best bet is to use [a listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)